# Angular interfering with custom events?

Tags: angularjs

Does Angular do anything under the hood that could be interfering with custom events?

I'm developing a media app for Playstation 3 and 4.  Such apps are developed in HTML5, and I'm using Angular 1.3 Beta 7 as the framework.  The PS4 sends internal event messages to the application layer like below

```
window["accessfunction"] = function ( response ) {

    console.debug ( "window.accessfunction " + response );

}
```

So, for example, when I disconnect the PS4 from the network, a message will be received by "window.accessfunction".  This works as expected when I do not use Angular, but as soon as I introduce Angular, my disconnection message is not received until I reconnect again.

Unless you have a devkit you won't be able to test this and I've filed a support request with Sony, but from the description, can anyone think of a reason why Angular might interfere with this process?

Thanks

Comment: Does introducing Angular mean just loading angular.js?

Comment: Hi.  Problem resolved.

It's caused by Web Inspector not updating the debug console output immediately.

Comment: I was wondering if that can be done in Angular2+